# What is a "fast" hash function for a bloom filter?

Tags: hash, bloom-filter

Assuming that I'm studying and tuning an hash function for a bloom filter, what is the maximum number of cycles that takes to compute an hash using a function that could possibly widely accepted as "fast" ?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you use a bloom filter to avoid disk I/O, then it might make sense to spend more time in the hash function, so that you have as few as possible hash collisions. Bloom filters are used for example to avoid disk I/O for a [log structured merge tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree). Usually it doesn't make sense to use a [cryptographically secure hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), but something similar, for example [xxhash](https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/) or [MurmurHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash).

If you want to use a bloom filter to avoid an in-memory lookup, then you probably want to use a faster hash function, for example just the XOR of the input, or use a [Fletcher checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum).

A good explanation about advantages / disadvantages of fast versus slow hash functions, and some tests, [are available here](http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions).

Comment: in general I'm planning to use a bloom filter for managing inputs and associated "actions" , nothing related to disk or storage in general, a 15/20 cycle hashing function is what ? fast ? slow ?

Comment: Do you mean 15 to 20 cycles per hash? That would be OK. Or 15 to 20 cycles per byte? That would slow in my view.

Comment: each hash; and what would be better ?

Comment: 15 to 20 cycles per hash is OK; there is probably no point in trying to speed it up further.